# Second derivative of a mapping

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if its second partial derivatives exist and are continuous then $f$ is twice differentiable. One writes its first derivative by means of the Jacobi matrix and the second one by means of the Hesse matrix. What is the correlate of the Hesse matrix and thus the second derivative in case of a mapping $\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix read this in order to understand what happen for a vector function.

Comment: @Vajra that is the Jacobian or first derivative, not the second derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand higher derivatives of a function $f:\mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R}^q$ one must leave the Euclidean spaces and enter the normed vector spaces. As such, let us consider a function $f:\mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}$ a function between two vector spaces. Such a function is said to be differentiable at a point $v \in \mathrm{V}$ if there exists a *continuous linear transformation* $L:\mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}$ such that $f(v + h) = f(v) + Lh + o(h)$ where $o(h)$ denotes a function of $h$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ h \neq 0}} \dfrac{\|o(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.$ It can then be shown that $L$ is uniquely defined and so it makes sense to write it as $f'(v).$ We can therefore derive a mapping from this procedure in which given a vector $v \in \mathrm{V}$ we associate the continous linear function $f'(v).$ We denote this new mapping as $f':\mathrm{V} \to \mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W}).$ Now, the space $\mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W})$ is the space of all linear function $\mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}$ that are continuous and we endowit with the canonical norm for linear functions
$$
\|u\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \dfrac{\|u(v)\|}{\|v\|}.
$$
Therefore, $f'$ is a function between two normed spaces. As such, we can consider its derivative. When $f'$ is differentiable at $v,$ then we will say that $f$ is **twice differentiable at $v.$** The uniqueness of the derivative show that the notation $f''(v)$ makes sense. Again, $f''$ can be regarded as a linear function from $\mathrm{V}$ into $\mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W})).$ The key part is that if $B \in \mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W}))$ then $B(v_1) \in \mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W})$ and so $B(v_1) \cdot v_2 \in \mathrm{W}.$ The mapping $(v_1, v_2) \mapsto B(v_1, v_2)$ is a *bilinear* function $\mathrm{V} \times \mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}.$ And we identify canonically every element of $\mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathsf{Lin}(\mathrm{V}, \mathrm{W}))$ with said bilinear function. Furthermore, it can be shown that the second derivative of any twice differentiable function is *symmetric* meaning that $f''(v) \cdot (h_1, h_2) = f''(v) \cdot (h_2, h_1),$ this is known as *Schwarz's theorem* (this is true regardless of the continuity of $f''$ at $v$)

Now, if $B$ is a *symmetric bilinear form* $\mathbf{R}^p \times \mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R}$ then, there exists a unique symmetric matrix, also denote by $B$, such that $B(v_1, v_2) = v_1^\intercal B v_2.$ The Hessian matrix at $v$ of a function $f:\mathrm{R}^p \to \mathrm{R}$ is the unique symmetric matrix representing the second derivative of $f$ at $v.$ If $f:\mathrm{R}^p \to \mathrm{R}^q$ then the second derivative is not longer scalar-valued and as such a matrix representation for it may not exists or need be interpreted correctly. In such a case, I think of $f$ as a vector of functions $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_q)$ and if $H_i$ denotes the Hessian of $f_i$ at $v,$ then I write the second derivative of $f$ at $v$ as $[H_1, \ldots, H_q]$ and assume it means coordinatewise evaluation $x^\intercal [H_1, \ldots, H_q] y = (x^\intercal H_1 y, \ldots, x^\intercal H_q y) \in \mathbf{R}^q.$

I hope this helps.

*Suggested readings:*

1. Foundations of modern analysis by Jean Dieudonné, chapter 8.

That's it, there are not other books treating calculus this way as good as Diudonné's. You can read Cartan's more detailed exposition but Cartan himself states that he follows Dieudonné's book to more detail. (Cartan's has 100 pages while Dieudonné's 49 pages.)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting answer (the last part). I could not find what I was looking for in any book. While the first derivative of a function is related to the Jacobian matrix of f (in that case it is a gradient), the second one to the Hessian of f, it appeared strange that I could not find a similar correlate for vector-valued mappings when it comes to the second derivative, the first derivative being again related to the Jacobian.

Comment: When I learned calculus, I also was flabbergasted that highers order derivatives where skipped altogether (the Hessian appeared but just as a matrix of second partial derivatives, which was unsatisfying). But more, notice how you mentioned that if the second partials are continuous then the second derivative exists? Well, actually that is _false_ at face value, you need the second partial to exists everywhere in a ball and be continuous at the centre of the ball.

Comment: @William M. May I ask which book of Cartan do you refer in your last paragraph?

Comment: @balcinus Differential Calculus by Henri Cartan. Cartan does not talk about Hessian matrices or about matrices in general as he deals directly with the operator and the rule of correspondence defining them. I wrote a book on differential calculus on normed spaces and this book does deal simultaneously with finite dimensions and infinite dimensions, so I translated most results to matrix language and spelled out the identifications. Unfortunately, the book is not in print as it was rejected for being too technical (it is also written in Spanish).