# Taylor Series For Vector Function of Vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

Let $\textbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ be a nonlinear vector function. I would like to take the Taylor series of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ about a point $\mathbf{x}_0$, retaining the first three terms. I know that Taylor expansion of $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ about $\mathbf{x}_0$, retaining only the first two terms, is:

$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) \approx \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0) + \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0),$

where the matrix $G\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$ is defined by:

$\mathbf{G} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}_1}{\partial \mathbf{x}_1}\Big|_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0} & \dots & \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}_1}{\partial \mathbf{x}_n}\Big|_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}_N}{\partial \mathbf{x}_1}\Big|_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0} & \dots & \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}_N}{\partial \mathbf{x}_n}\Big|_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0}  \end{bmatrix}.$

How do I extend this to the three-term approximation of $f$? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is excellent and I have no idea why people downvoted it, it was also very clear.

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169844/second-derivative-of-a-mapping/4170302#4170302

Would this suffice or do you need to expand more?

Comment: In a nutshell, you will have $f(x + h) \approx f(x) + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k \frac{1}{k!} \sum\limits_{i_1 + \ldots + i_p = j} \binom{k}{i_1, \ldots, i_p} \partial_1^{i_1} \cdots \partial_p^{i_p} f(x) h_1^{i_1} \cdots h_p^{i_p}$ where $f:\mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R}^q$ and $\partial_1^{i_1} \cdots \partial_p^{i_p} f(x)$ are _vectors_ obtained by partial differentiation with (I hope) obvious notation.

Comment: @WilliamM. I think that should be $j!$ right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$